# If value contains one or more from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a list of items...

Item A
Item B
Item C
Item D

I can tell the code to not display any items that contain A like so:

```
exclusions = new Array("A")
if (v.value.indexOf(exclusions) > -1) {
}
else {
DO SOMETHING
}
```

Where I get stuck is if I want it to exclude more than one, like so:

```
exclusions = new Array("A", "B")
if (v.value.indexOf(exclusions) > -1) {
}
else {
DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a regex.

```
var matches = "there is a boy".match(/[ab]/);
if (matches === null) {
   // neither a nor b was present
}
```

If you need to construct a regex from strings, you can do it like

```
var matches = "there is a boy".match(new RegExp("[ab]"));
```

If you have an array of strings like `['a', 'b']` then you need to do something like

```
var pattern = yourArray.join('');
var regex = new RexExp(pattern);
```

here we construct a string which is a pattern, and then create a new regex based on that pattern.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, but I can't seem to put it into context.

Comment: To ref my original code block, would I need var matches = v.value.match(/[ab]/);

Comment: Got it sorted thank to this answer, It was the "there is a boy" example that threw me for a min.  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering in pseudo - code fashion:

```
exclusions = new Array("A", "B");
exclusion_found = false;
for (int i=0; i< exclusions.length; i++) {
    if (v.value.indexOf(exclusions[i]) > -1) {
        exclusion_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!exclusion_found) {
    DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way of using `indexOf`, utilising [`Array#every` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var val = v.value;
if(exclusions.every(function(x) { return val.indexOf(x) === -1 })) {
    // val does not contain any string in `exclusions`
}
```